Falla al obtener el tipo file en mi elemento usando Selenium Python para carga de archivo
Estoy tratando de subir un archivo, sí logré dar clic en el elemento pero no he logrado enviarle mi archivo con sendkeys.
mi html es este:
<app-solicitud-form-requisitos _ngcontent-kal-c8="" class="col-md-12" _nghost-kal-c16="" xpath="1"><input _ngcontent-kal-c16="" accept="application/pdf,image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg" id="inputArchivo" style="display: none;" type="file"><div _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="col12 titulo-doc"><div _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="icono-izq-registro"><img _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="img-usuario" src="assets/img/documentacion.svg"></div><div _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="texto-der-registro"> Documentación. <br _ngcontent-kal-c16=""> Formatos permitidos jpg, png o pdf. Tamaño máximo 2MB. <br _ngcontent-kal-c16=""><br _ngcontent-kal-c16=""> 1/9 documentos obligatorios <br _ngcontent-kal-c16=""></div><!----><div _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="ng-star-inserted"><mat-progress-bar _ngcontent-kal-c16="" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" class="mat-progress-bar mat-primary" mode="determinate" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="11.111111111111114"><svg class="mat-progress-bar-background mat-progress-bar-element" focusable="false" height="4" width="100%"><defs><pattern height="4" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="8" x="4" y="0" id="mat-progress-bar-15"><circle cx="2" cy="2" r="2"></circle></pattern></defs><rect height="100%" width="100%" fill="url('/portalapoyos/cuenta/solicitud/seguimiento/7e086884-cd21-4fea-b94e-5ca8f4e308d1#mat-progress-bar-15')"></rect></svg><div class="mat-progress-bar-buffer mat-progress-bar-element"></div><div class="mat-progress-bar-primary mat-progress-bar-fill mat-progress-bar-element" style="transform: scaleX(0.111111);"></div><div class="mat-progress-bar-secondary mat-progress-bar-fill mat-progress-bar-element"></div></mat-progress-bar></div><!----></div><!----><!----><form _ngcontent-kal-c16="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-kal-c16="" formgroupname="solicitante" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"><table _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="table stripe table-stripe tabla-responsiva"><thead _ngcontent-kal-c16=""><tr _ngcontent-kal-c16="" role="row"><th _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="tcol1">Documento</th><th _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="tcol1">Vigencia</th><th _ngcontent-kal-c16=""></th><th _ngcontent-kal-c16=""></th><th _ngcontent-kal-c16=""></th></tr></thead><tbody _ngcontent-kal-c16=""><!----><tr _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="cambiorenglon-apoyos ng-star-inserted"><td _ngcontent-kal-c16=""><!----><span _ngcontent-kal-c16="" mattooltip="El documento es obligatorio y aun no se ha proporcionado" style="color: red; margin-right: 2px; touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" class="ng-star-inserted" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-28" cdk-describedby-host="">*</span><!----><span _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="mobile-label">Documento: </span><span _ngcontent-kal-c16=""><strong _ngcontent-kal-c16="">Acta de Nacimiento Beneficiario</strong></span><!----><!----><!----><!----><div _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="col-md-12 pt-6 ng-star-inserted"><!----><!----><span _ngcontent-kal-c16="">No cuenta con manifiestos vigentes</span></div></td><td _ngcontent-kal-c16=""><span _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="mobile-label">Vigencia: </span>  </td><td _ngcontent-kal-c16=""><!----><div _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="ng-star-inserted"><!----><span _ngcontent-kal-c16="" class="hand ng-star-inserted" mattooltip="Seleccionar un archivo" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-29" cdk-describedby-host="" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><img _ngcontent-kal-c16="" alt="Subir" class="ico-adjuntar" src="assets/img/adjuntar.svg"> Seleccionar un archivo... </span><!----></div><!----></td>

mi código es este:
try:
    carga = WebDriverWait(driver, 80).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='section-bar-6']/div/app-solicitud-form-requisitos/form/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/span")))
    carga = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/app-root[1]/app-public-layout[1]/div[1]/app-solicitud-form[1]/div[1]/app-solicitud[1]/form[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section[7]/div[1]/app-solicitud-form-requisitos[1]/form[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[3]/div[1]/span[1]").send_keys("C://Users//dulce.ayala//PycharmProjects//Automation//Imagenes//INE.png")
    time.sleep(25)
    print("Carga archivo")
except TimeoutException as ex:
    print(ex.msg)
    print("No se encontró el Elemento carga archivo")

Mi resultado es este:
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

A alguien le ha sucedido algo similar? De antemano gracias por su ayuda.
